# Android Application Backend from scratch

Tags: android, web-services, mobile, backend, mbaas

I am developing an android application which needs a backend to process login and store data remotely on a server. I have previously worked with a BaaS service "Parse" for android. but since this is my final year project for my university I need to develop a backend from scratch, I have never worked with web services. I need some guidance on how to approach this and which framework will be the best to work with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to build a server application that allows you query data from your android app?

I'm not an expert on this since i just started coding myself, but I did do some research and it seems to be a very viable option to implement a RESTful API on the server side. The wiki article is pretty specific about how it works.

If you can use PHP the slim framework allows you to get a scrappy prototype RESTful API up in less then an hour if you familiar with the server configuration. It seems to be sophisticated enough to drive small and medium sized projects (maybe even big projects; I can't tell to be honest.)

On the start page you can see an example that allows you to query for a "hello, world" string from the API with less then 50 lines of code.
http://www.slimframework.com/

Where the example returns a "hello world" string you would perform database queries using PHP and return your results as json objects to your client.

The benefits of this are that you can use this Backend for different clients: Android, iOS or even your own browser-based web application.

This also makes it easy replace / port the backend once requirements change since it's very easy to implement the same API using other technologies and languages that fit the requirements better.